# Profile "Answers" section: Indicator if own answer has competing accepted answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, profile-page, accepted-answer

At the moment the ***Answers*** section on every user profile has two styles for the answer count:

[image]

- white background, grey font: **Own answer is not accepted**
- green background, olive font: **Own answer is accepted**

Usually I regularly return to my *"white answers"* to see

- if the OP has further questions or remarks and is not happy with my answer provided, so I can improve it.
- or if there are correct answers, but none accepted, I kindly ask the OP to accept an answer.

But there is also the common case:

- There is an accepted answer, which is not mine. Everything is fine, problem solved, usually not much further action required.
  But the answer count box in my profile remains white and keeps telling me *"Hey, the problem is **not solved**! Have a look at this question again and see what is missing!"* - what I do, just to see that there is another answer, which is accepted and satisfies all the needs of the OP.

As I can't remember for which of all my *"white answers"* this is the case, I have the following proposal:

**Can we have a third answer count box style for the case, that there is a competing accepted answer?**

For example: white background, grey font, bold green box-frame, which could then look like:

[image]

---

This feature is not meant to "steal accepted answers", it is supposed to make it easier for users to look back and see if everything is done to get a problem solved. The basic requirement for that is to actually see which questions are still unsolved.

The comment, that the time invested in improving slightly older answers should rather be used for answering new questions is a fair point, but I think a lot of users prefer to write fewer, but better answers, which completely solve the OP's problem, than a lot of quick&dirty answers. It's probably a matter of taste.

Comment: Is your aim to have your good (but not accepted) answers to stand put from your okay/bad answers? Just checking if I understand.

Comment: I didn't know I missed this. Now I do.

Comment: @JustinLardinois I don't quite understand your comment. I don't care how the answer scores look to others, it is more a help for myself, which of my answers may need further attention.

Comment: Another thing is, that I'm active in a small tag, which is maintained by a relatively small group of people. We have a high *unanswered question* quote. I don't have the time to read all old unanswered questions every day, but the least I can do is to take care about questions I have answered and it would be nice to distinguish between unanswered (no accepted answer) and answered questions (accepted, but not visible for me, without clicking the question/answer) straight from ones own profile.

Comment: So you don't have time to read unanswered, even if old, questions but you do have time to read already answered (and by yourself, too) questions? And you say there is also a high *unanswered question* quote?

Comment: I don't think the answers section should be changed. I would like a search option though, e.g. `is:question hasaccepted:no answeredby:me`

Comment: @AndriyM Yes to revise a question, which I have already answered is much faster than thinking about an old question, where the OP may doesn't even care anymore if it gets answered or not. Yes, the e.g. Matlab tag has a high unanswered question quote of 50% weekly and 25% in total. Basically because there are not enough high-rep users to deal with all the newcomers which never accept any answers (besides we can't manage to close bad questions fast enough and try to answer them anyway by using our mentalist skills, just to get them answered)

Comment: I didn't realise this was the case I thought green background meant the question had an accepted answer regardless of who's it was, now I feel dirty! I guess this is also the case when viewing other user profile summary screens as well?

Comment: Yep just confirmed this is the case. Other users profile summary shows questions with their accepted answers as green background and white on others even if another accepted answer exists.

Comment: At first, I thought the reason you want this feature is to be able to improve your answer until it's get accepted (i.e stealing the acceptance), which I somewhat feel is not so constructive (sorry for premature judgement). But after reading Lankymart's comment, it would be useful to let me know that the question I answered already has an accepted answer, whoever they are, so I don't have to check my answer once in a while again. +1

Comment: @AndrewT. No, "stealing the acceptance" is not the intention. (in our small tag it wouldn't work anyway, without making enemies...). But often the own answer is the only one, for other users already out of focus, and it needs either improvement or a hint for the OP (newcomers mostly) is necessary on how to use the accepting feature. All actions which wouldn't be necessary if one would know, that the OP already is satisfied.

Comment: It would be great to have this feature. I am mostly active in the android tag and there are a lot of questions from new users who don't understand or know how Stack Overflow works. Having an indicator wether a question has an accepted answer at all would be really helpful to discern which questions I need to revisit. At the moment I have to click through all my recent answers to check if the answers need some additional work or if the OP needs some additional guidance.

Comment: I think I'd prefer the characterization "Question has another accepted answer" or "Question has an accepted answer (but it isn't this answer)" to the "competing" description.  The net result is much the same.

Comment: Just seeing this now. This is a neat idea!

Comment: Awesome idea, I usually face it and it really confuses me, and i go to the question to see if the question has been solved