# Notification when another answer is accepted

Tags: feature-request

Currently you get notified (and receive points) when your answer is marked as accepted. Can a notification be sent also when a different answer than yours is accepted? I think this will increase the quality of answers here, as people can see how the accepted answer looks like, without having to go through the list of all answers and check the corresponding questions.

Comment: Notifications are displayed in the Achievements dropdown.  It is a good-news delivery mechanism, SE carefully avoided delivering bad news and anything that is not actually an achievement.  Too much drama.  It doesn't help you that much anyway, accept rates at SO are very low.

Comment: It helps me as I periodically go through the questions that I answered to and wasn't selected, to see if another answer was selected or not. You can learn a lot from a selected answer and you can become more productive here on SO if you take the example of good/great answers.

Comment: Please do note that just because an answer is accepted, doesn't mean that the answer is good... It only means it was useful to the questioner.

Comment: I know this, none the less I'd like to easily spot questions that I answered and accepted someone else's answer, that answer might help me too, as many accepted answers contain more information that I posted, information that I might not have been aware of, thus helping me too in increasing the knowledge level.

Answer (score 11):

I think a notification might be overkill. Some users may post a lot of content and once they answer they may not wish to return to the post unless somebody comments on their answer.

Most users would probably consider another answer being accepted as, "there's nothing further required on that post"... so wouldn't want to be notified about it.

A better solution might be to update the styling on user profiles, so that questions that have been answered are styled to indicate there is an accepted answer that isn't yours with the answer icon turning green:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

So an updated profile with new styles might look like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Styling differentiated as:

1. Your answer is accepted
2. Another answer has been accepted
3. No accepted answer

Simply using the following styles for the `A` would achieve this:

```
<span class="icon-a accepted"></span>
```

Comment: That would work well, and the user will not have to individually open every question that he's interested.

Comment: Also: [Profile “Answers” section: Indicator if own answer has competing accepted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288184/profile-answers-section-indicator-if-own-answer-has-competing-accepted-answer?rq=1)

Comment: Can the indicator also be added also to the `activity`->`answers` tab, currently it appears only on the `top posts` section from the `profile` section

Comment: @JonasCz knew i'd seen something similar somewhere but i couldn't find it