# Could the new green color for accepted/unaccepted questions be tweaked against yellow favorite/ignored tags background?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

The new (answered) color scheme is a bit vivid against the background of a a question containing favorite tags. The bright green color also gives the accepted answer box a bit of a "halo" against the background when your eyes aren't absolutely focused on it.

[image: Answers against favorite/ignored tags background]

On the choice of accepted/unaccepted colors:

- Should a question with an accepted answer should be noticed more now than a question with unaccepted answers?
- Does the more vivid shade of green unintentionally draw focus away from even the question title/body itself?

Would it be possible to tweak these colors to lower the contrast between unaccepted and accepted answers, and make the accepted answer not be as distinct from the yellow background?

Comment: In my opinion questions with answers don't need a green background; it's unnecessary and misleading. The simple numerical indicated on the number of answers is enough. Only questions with *accepted* answers should have the green background.

Comment: I did like the how the previous (olive) design distinguished between accepted and unaccepted questions by simply changing the number's foreground color.

Comment: @TylerH "Only questions with *accepted* answers should have the green background." Are you suggesting that the lighter shade of green should be used for the accepted answer, so it doesn't stand out too much? I think that's a good solution.

Comment: Well, I think the forest green one is nicer than the pale green one personally, but it doesn't really matter much to me. I think *a* green background should indicate an accepted answer, and the simple existence of (non-accepted) answers should be indicated by the number that's already there (e.g. 1, 3, 12, etc.).

Comment: @TylerH I know zip about graphics design, but the paler color allows the numeric text foreground color to be dark (instead of light), which matches the rest of the text color choices. If you look at the sidebar now, *Related* accepted answers are white on green, compared to black on grey.

Comment: Yes, but the pale green practically disappears against that background in grayscale.

Comment: Is there a meta-(meta post) regarding this design change (green bars)? I could not find any. And this new color thing looks quite weird with flux\redshift turned on.

Comment: @TylerH It looks more like lime green to me.

Comment: I seriously thought my tablet was broken when I first hopped on SO. Then I got on my laptop and realized this hideous thing is normal.

Comment: @BenUsman There are a couple (search for "Whats with the green?" and "Green/White color" on Meta). And I can guarantee you that they don't design with brightness attenuators like f.lux in mind :-/

Comment: Against white, the green looks fine, but against the peach, it just clashes way too much. Hard on the eyes. It like goes against everything color theory teaches

Comment: Contrast ratio of 1:4.20 with the font vs. background of the unaccepted green box. Should be 1:4.5 minimum. :(

Comment: Put this back - green on green background makes it hard to read - thought it was issue with site, the way it was before was fine!

Comment: This whole recoloring attempt is actually a good opportunity to reconsider the suggestion made [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288184/2605073), isn't it?

Comment: That strong green keeps drawing my eye. I don't need to be drawn to already answered questions.

Comment: A green rectangle signifies that __I__ got some rep. It should __not__ be here at all. Not anywhere except my notification area at the top. Many other wesites don't understand how irritating this is. But SO __really really really should know better__..

Comment: why was this changed, is there some rationale somewhere?

Comment: I think a reverse color scheme of the simple *answered* pale green with dark green text would work well and would simplify the palatte (i.e. dark green bg and light green text)

Comment: @eis It was changed [to improve performance and consolidate the CSS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321419/4151918).

Comment: People really hate change! Perhaps it's worth stepping back and just considering that this may not be such a terrible change?

Comment: I was working fine and rather elegant and now it looks clumsy and sends wrong signals. I'd love to get a choice. Hey, if the powers that be really have too much time at their hands, why not make it configurable?

Comment: @TaW I might register a domain just to give an answer to that question, because whenever there is any change to the visuals of a public website, somebody always brings it up. Configurability is not free; it messes with caching; it multiplies your testing effort for every change; it means people raising bugs against all sorts of weird configurations you didn't intend; etc. And if you read around, you'll see the change came about in the process of making things *easier* to maintain, so quite the opposite of having too much time on their hands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Meta change its accepted answer styling to UX?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277863/can-meta-change-its-accepted-answer-styling-to-ux)

Comment: Bikeshedding must go on. :/

Comment: @ IMSoP: Yeah, well, I wrote it with tongue in cheek. But still: If switching four colors makes any impact on maintainabilty I really hope SO is not in serious trouble. -  And: You did get the sematics wrong: 'Green' means 'You'  (a word which here means 'I') got 'Reputation points' not somebody else. It means I __should__ look not I __needn't__ look because it already has an accepted answer.

Comment: The background color of favorite questions has been tweaked and no longer matches the image in your question. Mind updating the screenshot?

Comment: @TaW Handling the ability of users to arbitrarily change parts of the stylesheet absolutely impacts maintainability. Every time you do any styling work, you've got to work out if it needs to consult the user's preferences; even if you offer the user set palettes, any new element must be fitted into the palette, and its look tested in every possible palette. Not to mention every time you come up with a performance optimisation, you've got to check it doesn't serve people the wrong styles somehow. (PS: "You did get the semantics wrong" - why is this addressed to me? I don't work for SO!)

Comment: when i first loaded SO yesterday and saw the new change, for a second i thought "huh, that's different." then i thought, "looks pretty good". that's all there is to it. it's a minor change; who cares. everyone will get used to it, i promise you.

Comment: Well, that is __not__ what I meant. I'd like to pick old or new style, that is all, not arbitrary colors..  But getting rid of the fat green stains would be good enough.. 'You' here was a word that meant: 'Whoever designed that new scheme'..

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Thanks for pointing that out.  The background color change is an improvement, but the original screenshot shows the reason for the question.

Comment: @TylerH Regarding your very first comment (which I agree with), that would make it [consistent with the related questions](http://imgur.com/iH0ntHi) section, which only goes green for questions with accepted answers.  Note the number is the vote count rather than answer count, but not being light green when it has answers is inconsistent with the main question list.

Comment: @TaW Don't know how to do it myself, but I believe you can configure your own color scheme through a user script.

Comment: @TaW I realise you weren't entirely serious, but people always bring this up, and your logic just doesn't make sense. Is this change really the single most important & controversial design change in the history of the site, deserving of a unique place on the settings page? Of course not! So what exactly would be configurable, what would the future scope be, how would it impact future development? It's really never as simple as "if someone had 5 minutes, they could hack in an if statement just for me, and then never think about it again".

Comment: When I first saw it yesterday (well, did it change only yesterday? coz I dunno) I thought my head is playing with me, coz I did not have enough sleep the day before. ;-)

Comment: @bahrep: No. Bikeshedding is when a group of people focus _solely_ on minutiae. This is not that. Meta has _plenty_ of posts about very fundamental and broad facets of the system. This is one post about a fairly reasonable UI concern. Do you wish people would ignore all small UI issues because "bikeshedding"? Silly.

Comment: Actually it's difficult to know which question is already has marked answer, because both one have green color. So at-least do color change for at least one. My view is change the color of question without any marked answer. the green color with dark background (question with accepted answer) is cool.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I realize that this post was made yesterday and since then we've updated [the greens and favorite tag question highlight background color (wow that's a mouthful!)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321413/new-styles-new-shade-of-green-for-accepted-answers-its-not-easy-being-gree)

That being said, I didn't want this post to go unanswered.

> Should a question with an accepted answer should be noticed more now than a question with unaccepted answers?

This is kind of a subjective question. Should it be noticed more? In my opinion, yes. For those looking for an answer, it sends a signal that there's a potential answer here for their problem. For those looking to answer questions, it sends a signal that you probably don't need to write an answer since one has already been provided and your time may be better spent on an unanswered or answered (but not accepted) question.

> Does the more vivid shade of green unintentionally draw focus away from even the question title/body itself?

The newer green that we rolled out today combined with removing the lighter green background and lightening the favorite tag question background color addresses this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the improvements, and for addressing the issues! I can appreciate that there would be a far greater number of people looking for answers, than those looking to answer questions, so it's a reasonable choice to make the accepted answers more noticeable. Thanks again!

Comment: previous one is better. accepted answer question have something in yellow. current green color(dark one) is great but use yellow if answer accepted for any question. Means question without any accepted answer will be dark green, but with accepted one have yellow.