# The accepted answer checkmark's color is still on the old green theme

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It's not easy going green!

Regarding all the talk about changing the greens:

- [New Styles? New shade of green for accepted answers? It's not easy... being green](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321413/74757) and
- [Could the new green color for accepted/unaccepted questions be tweaked against yellow favorite/ignored tags background?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321414/could-the-new-green-color-for-accepted-unaccepted-questions-be-tweaked-against-y)

I noticed this morning that the accepted-answer checkmark is still on the old theme:

[image]

Was an exception made for this element or should it be corrected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah yes. Sigh. [Sprite files.](http://www.johnstejskal.com/blog-files/ken-sprite-sheet.png)

This has been corrected and will be fixed with the next production build.