# Favorites highlight color and status answered color are too light

Tags: bug, design

Reiterating [Contrast on highlighted favorites is too low](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283937/contrast-on-highlighted-favorites-is-too-low) for the last redesign.

I can barely see the difference between normal and highlighted (`.tagged-interesting`, `#FFFBEC`) entries, and the [contrast calculator](http://www.had2know.com/technology/color-contrast-calculator-web-design.html) is solidary with me:

```
Brightness difference = 5 (Fail)
Hue difference = 23 (Fail)
```

*Do note that "pass/fail" here is tailored for foreground/background contrast while this is background/background. Still, the difference is low even for this.* To get you the scale, the pass criteria for fg/bg are 150 and 500; I couldn't yet find any specific guidelines.

To add insult to injury, my LCD screen "skews whitepoint" (very light colors become pure white) on high contrast settings, making them *literally* indistinguishable in this case. (This isn't something to directly act upon, of course, just another evidence on how low contrast can be troublesome.)

Another problematic color is `rgba(69,191,99,0.25)`, the foreground for `"status answered"`. With the alpha blending, [it's effectively](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/w3c-wai-ig/2012OctDec/0011.html) `rgb(115,207,138)`:

```
Brightness difference = 83 (Fail)
Hue difference = 305 (Fail)
```

Comment: They [tweaked the favorites highlight color to not clash with the green accepted answer box](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321414/could-the-new-green-color-for-accepted-unaccepted-questions-be-tweaked-against-y).

Comment: There are a lot of crappy LCD monitors out there.  Get ahead by not ruining your eyes with cheap hardware, can't get those fixed when you're fourty-something.  Preserving the eyesight of SO users is a StackExchange Beneficial No-cost Service™

Comment: @HansPassant I only mentioned this as an additional example of how low-contrast palette can be problematic. Btw telling close colors apart _is_ a strain on the eyes.

Comment: I also have difficulty to recognising favorite tag question from regular one . I feature should be revoke or change with different color that is light but also visible. @ivan_pozdeev

Comment: Some thoughts about how it should be: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278354/favorite-tag-highlighting/279316#278354

Comment: Even with good hardware, the current `.tagged-interesting` background is damn near impossible to discern from white. The `lightness` setting is way way to light (97/100 if I recall correctly), Dial that alone down to 93 or 94 and the contrast is usable. Without a change all you get is a headache trying to scan for the little tags below each question.